# Link function not called

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive defined as following -

```
.directive('codesection', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { current: '=', parent: '=', index: '=', params: '=' },
      controller: ['Messages', '$scope', 'Modals', 'framewidth', '$http', '$rootScope', function (Messages, $scope, Modals, framewidth, $http, $rootScope) {
          //code
      }],
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {              
          element.bind('mouseover', function (ev) {
              ev.stopPropagation();

              var wrappers = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('codesection'));
              angular.forEach(wrappers, function (value, key) {
                  angular.element(value).children('span').removeClass('br');
              });

              element.children('.codesection').children('span').addClass('br');
          });

      },
      compile: function (tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
          var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
          var compiledContents;
          return function (scope, iElement, iAttr) {
              if (!compiledContents) {
                  compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
              }
              compiledContents(scope, function (clone, scope) {
                  iElement.append(clone);
              });

          };
      },
      templateUrl: './partials/directives/codesection.html',          
      replace: true
  }
}])
```

The issue I am having is that Link functions is never called. Thank you!

P.S. The reason for the Compile logic is that the directive is recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that `link: function (scope, element, attr) {` isn't called then it's pretty clear: The compile function already returns a link function. What is defined as `link:` doesn't matter anymore and is ignored.

Comment: Looks like you are right but it wasn't really clear to me that compile  function takes place of link function. Can point me somewhere it's explained in more depth? Thanks.

Comment: @americanslon the [documentation for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) provides a detailed explanation